# Ignore field at runtime in Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using Objectify for an app back end. I have various classes in a module that's shared between the client and server as they're used in both. One of these classes has a field that's only relevant when it's used client side, so I don't need to persist it.

I can't set the @Ignore annotation at design time as the shared module doesn't import Objectify. Is it possible to set the ignore state of a field at run time when I register the class?

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to do this at present.

The best answer is probably to use something like the maven shade plugin to include `com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.*` with the shard lib.